# Constant global user type values in Go

Tags: go, static, constants, init, idioms

I want to arrange to compute a value that will not change after initialization.

I'd use const, but Go restricts consts to built-in types, IIUC.

So I figured I'd use `var`, and compute their initial values in `init()`

```
var (
    // ScreenBounds is the visible screen
    ScreenBounds types.Rectangle

    // BoardBounds is the total board space
    BoardBounds  types.Rectangle
)

func init() {
    ScreenBounds := types.RectFromPointSize(
        types.Pt(-ScreenWidth/2, 0),
        types.Pt(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))

    BoardBounds := ScreenBounds
    BoardBounds.Max.Y += TankSpeed * TotalFrames
}
```

Which is pretty good - but is there a way to "lock" the values once computed, other than to change the vars to unexported names, and then uses function-accessors to return their values?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. Variables are called that because their values can be changed. In Go there is no "final" or similar modifier. Simplicity of the language.

Only way to guard a variable from being changed from the outside is to make it unexported, and yes, then you need exported functions to get their values.

A workaround could be to not use variables but constants. Yes, you can't have struct constants, but if the structs are small, you may use its fields as separate constants, e.g.:

```
const (
    ScreenMinX = ScreenWidth / 2
    ScreenMinY = ScreenHeight / 2
    ScreenMaxX = ScreenWidth
    ScreenMaxY = ScreenHeight
)
```

Comment: yes - and could then have a function to create the needed `Rectangle` from those values also included with the constants.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can move these "constants"

```
func init() {
    screenBounds := types.RectFromPointSize(
        types.Pt(-ScreenWidth/2, 0),
        types.Pt(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))

    BoardBounds := ScreenBounds
    BoardBounds.Max.Y += TankSpeed * TotalFrames
}
```

into a separate package and define them as **unexportable** and also define an **exportable** function like this:

```
func GetScreenBounds() types.SomeType {
 return screenBounds
}
```

It's some overhead but it will provide you ability to use that constants securely.